# How to delete duplicate data based on two columns

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query that deletes duplicate data leaving only one duplicate data when two columns overlap.
Maybe because of a lot of data, but the following query doesn't work for a long time

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 
WHERE t1.idx < t2.idx AND t1.Nm = t2.Nm AND t1.product = t2.product;
```

Can this query do what I want? If not, what is the other way?

Comment: You should only join rows which are the same DELETE t1 FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t1.Nm = t2.Nm AND t1.product = t2.product)
WHERE t1.idx < t2.idx;

Comment: I tried the way you told me, but it's running for more than 5 minutes. The line is about 30000 lines, but does it take so long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Index on the 3 columns involved in the ON clause:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name
ON tablename (Nm, product, idx);
```

and execute the query like this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2 
WHERE t1.Nm = t2.Nm AND t1.product = t2.product AND t1.idx < t2.idx;
```

As you can see in this simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83bfb8ceaf829f84eb707fcf87385884), the query will be executed using the index.